# How to consider scrollbar with CSS

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a button spanning the right side of the window that will open a menu when clicked. When the scroll-bar appears on the page, however, the button nearly disappears behind it. My question is simply: how do I use CSS or JavaScript to take the scrollbar's width into consideration when calculating either the position or the width of the button? 
 Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='ui'>
        <div id='menu' class='x'>
            <div id='menuBtn'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#ui{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#menu{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

#menu.x{
    margin-right: -595px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}

#menu.x:hover{
    margin-right: -575px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px black;
}

#menu.o{
    margin-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 45px black;
}

#menuBtn{
    transition: all .5s;
    background-color: red;
    height: inherit;
    width: 45px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-right: groove darkgray 5px;
    border-left: groove darkgray 5px;
}
```

Comment: Scroll width would be considered by the browser by default. Guessing your button is absolute. Can you post your code in editor.

Comment: My button is fixed, which I can't necessarily change.

Comment: Post your button CSS code in editor. Would help us to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
#menuBtn{
    transition: all .5s;
    background-color: red;
    height: inherit;
    width: 45px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-right: groove darkgray 5px;
    border-left: groove darkgray 5px;
    position: absolute;   // try with fixed
    right: 0px;
}
```